# Android communication with asp.net web service

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, rest

I'm trying to post data to a asp.net web service but seems that I do not know how to do that. So I need to post data like this

eg. http://yoors.somee.com/Default.aspx?type=EmailInsert&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASS&name=MYNAME&email=MYEMAIL@PROVIDER.com&emailenabled=FALSE

After that I get JSON response like this

```
{"VALID":"success"}
```

For now I'm using this function, but seems It is not working for this purpose.
/

```
/ Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yoors.somee.com/Default.aspx?type=EmailInsert");
                // http://yoors.somee.com/Default.aspx?type=Email
                // Insert&username=ben&password=pass&name=alv
                //&email=ben@yahoo.com&emailenabled=false
                try {
                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",userName));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, response.getAllHeaders().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
```

So can anyone please guide me how to post data to this web service

Comment: Are you sure you need to do a post?  It looks like you can do a get (ie copying the url into the browser works).  In which case you can use something like: `new WebRequest(string.Format("http://yoors.somee.com/Default.aspx?type=EmailInsert&username={0}&password={1}&name={2}&email={3}&emailenabled=false", userName, password, name, email) ).GetResponse();`

Comment: What do you get if you replace `response.getAllHeaders().toString()` by `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`

Comment: @Skaard-Solo I get 200

Comment: So your call to the WS is Ok. I think it's more about the parameters.
Can you get the httppost URL before executing it ? You receive a FAIL or just something else ?

Comment: @Skaard-Solo can you give me an example how can i do that?

Comment: Can you give me the answer of the WS of your actual code ?

Comment: @Skaard-Solo I do not have the ws code, the web service is coded by another programmer, so I do not have the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34146/discussion-between-skaard-solo-and-bozidar-prcovski)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I'm not a asp.net specialist :/

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yoors.somee.com/Default.aspx?type=EmailInsert");
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",userName));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent()).useDelimiter("\\A");
                responseString = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
                Log.d("Debug", responseString);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
```

UPDATE :

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yoors.somee.com/Default.aspx?type=EmailInsert&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASS&name=MYNAME&email=MYEMAIL@PROVIDER.com&emailenabled=FALSE");
```

works fine, but it's not really pretty ... I think there is something to find with that !